# SPFx Unable to use 'fs' module

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am creating a SPFx web part which is using `fs` module, but getting error `Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`. I know this issue causing from `typescript` because of missing typings. Following is the exact error what my web part is displaying

> ***ERROR MESSAGE:
>
> ***Failed to load component "79bb3b95-9a04-44d5-8c56-6a8f6c93cf45" (SaketaIntranetManagerWebPart).
>
> Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component
>   "79bb3b95-9a04-44d5-8c56-6a8f6c93cf22" (HelloWorld).
>
> Original error: Error loading
>   https://component-id.invalid/79bb3b95-9a04-44d5-8c56-6a8f6c93cf22_0.0.1
>     Cannot find module "fs"
>
> ***CALLSTACK:
>
> _loadComponentImpl/<@https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader_en-us.js:16232:21

I also tried running this command `typings install dt~node --global --save` but getting duplicate identifier issue after that. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you try it as `npm install --save @types/node` ?

Comment: Still the same error. `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`

Comment: I checked my solution is having node package inside @types folder.

Comment: I have two problems: First why do I need 50 reputation to comment but i can do normal posts? Aren't comments more like a discussion and normal posts like "answers"? Wouldnt it be better to have reputation for normal posts excpet if you are the one writing the first article? Well all this doenst matter here so I come back to the topic with my second problem.
While the above answer is true, in normal webpack config u could do something like this:
node: { fs: 'empty' }, But i can't find any file thats matches this description:
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2279#iss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fs module is a part of Node.js and is not available inside web parts. You could use it in custom Gulp tasks but not inside web parts. On runtime web parts run in web browser and not on top of the Node.js runtime which would explain the error that you're getting.

Comment: how to solve this problem?
1. where can I find the webpack config file https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2279#iss in SPFX?
2. or alternative?